# Describing two-step iteration in terms of complete Boolean algebras.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Suppose $B$ is a complete Boolean and let $\dot{C}\in V^B$ be such that $$\|\dot{C}\text{is a complete Boolean algebra}\|_B=1.$$

Let us consider all $\dot{c}\in V^B$ such that $\|\dot{c}\in\dot{C}\|=1$ and the equivalence relation $c_1\equiv c_2$ if and only if $\|\dot{c_1}=\dot{c_2}\|=1$. Let $D$ be the set of equivalence classes of this relation. We can make $D$ an equivalence relation as follows: if $\dot{c_1}$ and $\dot{c_2}$ are in $D$, there is a unique $\dot{c}\in D$ such that $\|\dot{c}=\dot{c_1}+_{\dot{C}}\dot{c_2}\|=1$, then we let $\dot{c}=\dot{c_1}+_D\dot{c_2}$, we define similarly $\cdot_D$ and $-_D$.

Furthermore, $D$ is a complete Boolean algebra: If $X\subseteq D$, let $\dot{X}\in V^B$ be given by $dom(\dot{X})=X$ and $\dot{X}(\dot{c})=1$, then by the fullness of $V^B$ there is some $\dot{c}\in D$ such that $\|\dot{c}=\sum_{\dot{C}}\dot{X}\|=1$, then $\dot{c}=\sum_D X$.

In the proof of lemma 16.3 of Jech's *Set Theory*, the author states the following fact:

> Given any $b\in B$, there is a unique $\dot{c}\in D$ such that $\|\dot{c}=1_{\dot{C}}\|=b$ and $\|\dot{c}=0_{\dot{C}}\|=-b$.

Does anyone know why this is true?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply definition by cases of names.

$\{b,-b\}$ is a maximal antichain (or a partition of $1$ in terms of Boolean algebras). So we can define a name whose values are determined by that antichain.

Comment: Hello Asaf, I cannot follow, how can we make sure that for this name $\dot{c}$ we have $\Vdash_B\dot{c}\in\dot{C}$?

Comment: Well, $b\Vdash_B\dot c\in\dot C$ and $-b\Vdash_B\dot c\in\dot C$ therefore their sum, $1_B\Vdash_B\dot c\in\dot C$.

Comment: Ok, I see, but I don't know what you mean by "cases of names". What do you mean by "a name whose values are determined by that chain"?

Comment: Well, I don't fully remember the whole definition of names with Boolean algebras (and I always found that to be somewhat tedious in a lot of the time), but let me give you an example with just two singletons $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$. Consider the name $\{(\check 0,b),(\check 1,-b)\}$. Then $1_B$ forces that this name is a singleton whose element is an ordinal below $2$. I suppose that you can consider the name $\dot c$ as sort of $\dot c$ as $\dot 0\cdot b+\dot 1\cdot(-b)$ in some sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time :-)

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Comment: @CamiloArosemena Just to add to Asaf's answer, the fact that you can take "Boolean superpositions" of names over an antichain is usually called the mixing lemma.

Comment: @Miha: I recall that Joel corrected me about that name at least twice; but I still keep forgetting the name, and remembering the mixing property thingie. :-)

Comment: @MihaHabič, is this the fact used to prove that the forcing notion in the proof of the Solovay And Tennenbaum' Theorem in Jech's book has size $\leq\kappa$?

Comment: @Camilo: It's a fact used by pretty much everyone who ever proved something with forcing after 1965.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena Indeed, this is THE method to build any sort of name whatsoever.